# Is the set a linear subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the set $W=\{(a,2a,2):a∈R\} \subseteq \Bbb{R}^3$ a linear subspace $\Bbb{R}^3$ ? 
I thought about it and still don't know where to start.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the [requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace#Definition) for a space to be a linear subspace? Writing these down would be the best place to start, it should become clear what the answer is once you do that.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No it isn’t since $$\vec{0}\notin W$$

For a subspace all the following three properties must be satisfied:

$$1) \ \vec{0} \in W\\
2) \ \vec{v}+\vec{w} \in W\\
3) \ \vec{cv}\to c \cdot \vec{v} \ ,c \in \mathbb{R}$$

NOTE 
if a subset do not contain $\vec0$ It certanly is not a subspace, this is really the first check to do

EG in $\mathbb{R^3}$ the only possible subset are: $\vec{0}$, the line planes throughout the origin and  $\mathbb{R^3}$ itself

Comment: Also the scalar multiplication rule doesn't work - if $v\in W$, then $kv\not\in W$ if $k\ne 1$.